# Problem in check exercises in atomic kotlin Course Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.20]

Tags: kotlin, build.gradle

I am trying to go ahead with the atomic kotlin book and do the exercises using the Edu Tools plugin. I will get this error after writing the exercise and hitting the check button. I could not solve this problem by searching please help.

Screenshot of settings and errors : https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoS3O.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution here:

https://github.com/svtk/AtomicKotlinCourse/issues/64

Basically, what you have to do if to replace your buil.gradle with the buil.gradle from the repository.

That's all!